# Import HTML code inside another file using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

I have to import a big HTML file (section1) inside my Homepage. I tried to do it using jquery load function but when the section is loaded the Javascript of that code doesn't work (scrollTo function, Juery UI).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#section1').load('section1.html');
});
```

Can someone help me out where i am missing?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question multiple times.

Comment: why I can't ask another time the same question if anyone answered me in a reasonable way??